# Segmentation fault core dumped using strtok

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, strtok, coredump

I am trying to write my own scanf which it get numbers in format string to limit size of inputs. like instead of "%d" it uses "@5%d" which indicates that input can not be more than 5 digit.

I am using following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdarg.h>



/*
 * 
 */
char** str_split(char* a_str, const char a_delim);
void myscanf(char *input_format, ... );

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int x;
    myscanf("@2%d", &x);

    printf("%d", x);

    return 0;
}

void myscanf(char *input_format, ... ){
   va_list args;
   va_start(args, input_format);
   char** tokens;
   tokens = str_split(input_format, '@');
   tokens=tokens++;
   while(*tokens){

       int number;
       char format;
       char** parts;

       parts=str_split(*tokens,'%');
       number=atoi(*(parts));
       format= **(parts+1);

       char s[number+1];
       fgets(s,number+1,stdin);

       if(strlen(s)>number)
           perror("buffer overflow");

       switch(format){
           case 'd':{

                int* integer = va_arg(args,int*);
                *integer = atoi(s);
                break;
           }
           case 'f': {

               float* floatingpoint = va_arg(args,float*);
               *floatingpoint = atof(s);
               break;
           }
           case 'c': {
               if(strlen(s)>1)
                    perror("buffer overflow");
               char* character = va_arg(args,char*);
               *character = s[0];
               break;
           }
           case 's': {
               char *string = va_arg(args,char*);
               strcpy(string, s);
               break;
           }
       }
       tokens++;
   }
}

char** str_split(char* a_str, const char a_delim)
{
    char** result    = 0;
    size_t count     = 0;
    char* tmp        = a_str;
    char* last_comma = 0;
    char delim[2];
    delim[0] = a_delim;
    delim[1] = 0;

    /* Count how many elements will be extracted. */
    while (*tmp)
    {
        if (a_delim == *tmp)
        {
            count++;
            last_comma = tmp;
        }
        tmp++;
    }

    /* Add space for trailing token. */
    count += last_comma < (a_str + strlen(a_str) - 1);

    /* Add space for terminating null string so caller
       knows where the list of returned strings ends. */
    count++;

    result = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);

    if (result)
    {
        size_t idx  = 0;
        char* token = strtok(a_str, delim);

        while (token)
        {
            assert(idx < count);
            *(result + idx++) = strdup(token);
            token = strtok(0, delim);
        }
        assert(idx == count - 1);
        *(result + idx) = 0;
    }

    return result;
}
```

when i execute this, console shows

> Segmentation fault core dumped.

I used gdb to debug this and it indicates that the problem is with strtok.
gdb output:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./a.out...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
/home/core: No such file or directory.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/a.out 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
strtok () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strtok.S:186
186 ../sysdeps/x86_64/strtok.S: No such file or directory.
```

I really appreciate If anybody can fix this.

Comment: `string=s;` should be `strcpy(string, s);`

Comment: `result = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);` should be `result = malloc(sizeof *result * (count+1));`

Comment: thank you @mch ,good point but didn't solves segmentation fault

Comment: thank you @joop , but when I used it, it raised some errors

Comment: Why do you use the `C` tag for a `C++` question?

Comment: You are calling `strtok` with a string literal and it will try to write to it.

Comment: change this. char s[number]; fgets(s, number, stdin)   to char[number+1]; fgets(s, number+1, stdin)

Comment: @mch because it's **C** question, only `using namespace std`  and `cout` are from c++ and i'm using them only to test it

Comment: Why are you writing this? Standard scanf supports max field width.

Comment: @n.m. it's an exercise

Comment: As soon as you put your code into a C++ compiler C rules do not apply any longer. Only C++ rules apply. And the rules are different as they are different languages.

Comment: @Gerhardh I turned it to pure **C** and compiled it with c compiler and still same problem happen again. I used **C** tag so nobody use any C++ function in their future solutions

Comment: mch already mentioned what your problem is. `strtok` alters the string that you pass and you passed a string literal. If you still use a C++ compiler it is even of type `const char *`

Comment: You are using some things, which are invalid in C and other things, which are invalid in C++. Choose 1 language. joop's and JunheeShin's suggestions are only valid in C.

Comment: @mch the string literal thing that you mentioned was my problem. I fixed it and now it raise some other errors which is not related to segmentation fault. i'm gonna fix them. thanks alot.

Comment: If you control the conversion string syntax, I recommend the standard scanf syntax, i e. %5d.

Comment: @n.m. that's a good idea, I will change it

Comment: @mch I'm not familiar with stack overflow users routines but your answer about string literal in strtok solved my problem. if you want you can post it as an answer to this so i can accept it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `myscanf` with a string literal (`"@2%d"`), `myscanf` calls `str_split` with it, `str_split` will call `strtok` and `strtok` tries to write to it, which is not allowed.

A simple solution would be to create a buffer

```
char buffer[] = "@2%d";
myscanf(buffer, &x);
```

Another smaller mistake I noticed:
`tokens=tokens++;` is undefined behaviour, you should use just `tokens++;` to increment `tokens`.
You already noticed my comment about the `strcpy` and changed it in the example code.